# decompose array to subsets

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `Array` of `Integers` and I want to sort the array using `bubble sort`. Sorting the whole array is *slow*.

> So, I want to improve the sorting using the advantage of parallel computing and multithreading.

I want to decompose the big array into smaller one and then sort the small once in parallel and then merge all the small arrays to form a big one.

Now, the challenge is, *I have a `long Array`* and I want to break it to `subsets` and fill them with values from the `long array`.

**I tried but with came up with no success. Any help?**

Comment: Please show what you tried and what problems you ran into - otherwise you're just asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: (Note that you don't really need multiple arrays here - you could have each thread just sort a portion of the original array.)

Comment: yes you are right, I tried it but do u synchronization, the performance didn't get better.

Comment: Well why are you synchronizing? If you're sorting discrete parts of the array, you shouldn't need synchronization.

Comment: sorry, can make it a bit clear? coz if I get u right, one thread will sort halve of the array and the other will do the rest, and finally the whole array should be sort as well, then I though this is where it needs so synchronize.

Comment: Well you could perform the merge step into a new array if you want - but that would still be simpler than creating N separate arrays for the initial part, which is what your question is asking about. But if you still want to go for that approach, you really need to show what you tried and say exactly how it failed.

Comment: tnx !cool, I will stick to your advice and try it, if it failed I will post it

Comment: _Tip:_ Compare it with java 8's parallel streams.